# Insert using PDO inside looping

Tags: php, pdo

Sorry for pretty basic questions, but I'm quite frustrated with this error. Please check if something needs to be corrected. Illustration, I'm trying to save data to table A where I take the data from table B. Before saving, it checks, if the data from table B is not in table A, insert it.

This my code:

```
$sql1="select * from B where status=2";
$q1=$this->pdo->query($sql1);
$q1->execute();
$result1=$q1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result1 as $row) {
  $sql2="select * from A where idB='".$row['idB']."'";
  $q2=$this->pdo->query($sql2);
  $q2->execute();
  $result2=$q2->fetchAll();

  if(empty($result2)){
    $data = ['idB' => $row['idB'],'name' => $row['name'];
    $s_inreg="insert into A(idB,name) values(:idB,:name)";
    $stmt=$this->pdo->prepare($s_inreg);
    $ret=$stmt->execute($data);
  }
}
```

think there are 100 data, only 10 data stored successfully, the rest failed to save.

Comment: Whats the point of `$result2` as you never use it, and please prepare your query its so easy in PDO.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `$result2` is used in `if (empty($result2))`

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I smallified your Code, or at least the code that actually does stuff

```
$result1 = $this->pdo->query('
SELECT
    B.idB,
    B.name
FROM
    B
LEFT JOIN
    A ON A.idB=B.idB
WHERE
    B.status=2 AND IS NULL A.ibB
')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('
INSERT INTO
    A(idB,name) VALUES (:idB,:name)'
);  

foreach ($result1 as $row) $stmt->execute($row);
```

Assuming what you had was correct, lets look at the JOIN

```
select * from B where status=2
select * from A where idB='".$row['idB']."'
 //and the results of A are $row
 $row['name'] //<-- dont forget this field
```

If `A.idB` = `B.idB` we can join on this.  Then you only use `idB` and `name` so instead of `*` we can use those 2 both from B (because `$row` was from `B`).

We can display this as sort of a half way point:

```
select B.idB,B.name from B where status=2
select * from A where A.idB=B.idB
```

Which when we join them:

```
select 
    B.idB,B.name
from 
    B
LEFT JOIN  #left JOIN
    A ON A.idB=B.idB
WHERE
       B.status=2
   AND
       IS NULL A.ibB #records from B where no A.idB exists.
```

AS Pointed out in the comments:

You basically want all records from B which do not have a record that matches in A.

For this we can use a LEFT JOIN.  Which will return all the records from the LEFT side of the JOIN (table `B`) regarless if they have a JOINED record in `A` the right side.

Then we just need to keep the records from the Left side `B` that have `null` for the `A.ibB` value, which we can do with `IS NULL A.ibB`.

These missing records are the ones we want to insert at the end:

---

Then lets look at the PDO code:

```
$q1=$this->pdo->query($sql1);
/// $q1->execute(); <--------------------- no need for this
$result1=$q1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now `$this->pdo->query()` returns false or a PDOStatement object, and `[PDOSTatement]->fetchAll()` can be joined by the return.

So we can do away with all those local variables and write it this way.

```
 $result1 = $this->pdo->query($sql1)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This works best if you have PDO set to throw exceptions, then you don't have to worry about it returning FALSE when if fails, because it will just throw an Exception instead.

In the same manner as we only use the SQL string one time, we can just put that right in, and get rid of `$sql1`.  The same is true for the insert query:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO A(idB,name) VALUES (:idB,:name)');  

foreach ($result1 as $row) $stmt->execute($row);
```

But with one or two, notes.  HERE because we trimed back what we pulled from the first query to only what we needed, and everything is named the same, we can just put the `$row` right into `execute`.  The other thing to note is to prepare the query outside of the loop.  We can re-use the `PDOStatement` as many times as we want and the DB only needs to interpret the SQL the first time, which saves a bit of performance for us.

**SUMMERY**

If it's easier for you to read, keep the local variables. I like to get rid of them because I don't like typing very much as I write a ton of code so I try to write as little as I need to, to do the job.  But, I've been doing this for a long time so I can read the more complex code fairly easily.

I just wanted to show it this way because, I don't think it's represented well in many examples on how much you can reduce your code and still have it do the same thing.  And less code to look at is less code to debug (to a limit).

Cheers.

Comment: I think your join logic is inverse to what OP wants. Your query will select all the `B` records that have a matching `idB` in `A`.

Comment: HaHA, your right @Phil - I blame my Dyslexia on it.   I need a Left Join with IS NULL, At least I think so figuring it out in my head.

Comment: thanks for great analytic, this is what I need.

Btw, as you have already demonstrated, JOIN can indeed be used when the table is in the same database. But with the same case, what if two tables such as A and B are in different databases? Of course JOIN is rather difficult for us to use.

Comment: Mysql, can actually join between two tables in different databases.  Not all Databases can do this, so it's generally discouraged.  You just need to include the databases  `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM database1.table AS a JOIN database2.table AS b ....`  Dont tell anyone but I actually do this all the time.  But that is because we have 3 different systems integrated, 2 are 3rd Party products, 1 is what I built,  So I cant modify the databases of the 3rd party Apps, and to put it in mine would require needless maintenance.

Comment: yes, before that thank's @ArtisticPhoenix fo your help.

Comment: Basically We have `Wordpress` for the theming and Content, Then we have a 3rd party Membership and Subscription platform that handles Client profiles, logins, eCommerce etc.   And last we have `CodeIgniter` that handles all the heavy coded stuff, like search forms, our online service, database CRUD etc...  And that is only half the site, there is a whole separate WordPress site that is public.  The previous one I described is a `ssae 18 soc 2` certified server that sits  behind a reverse proxy in a DMZ.  It's heavy stuff.  (and that is but  1 of 5 business sites I manage)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a MySQL database, you could do this with one query using the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax ...

```sql
INSERT INTO A (`idB`, `name`)
SELECT `idB`, `name` FROM B
WHERE B.status = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM A
  WHERE A.idB = B.idB
)
```